# Django Meta class abstract changing from True to False

Tags: python, django, django-models

I understand that when a class inherits from an Abstract Django Model, it will not inherit the meta attribute `abstract = True`, which makes sense.

However in the below example nothing has inherited from it, but yet it's `Meta.abstract` is `False` even though its defined to be `True`:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase


class MyMeta(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        """Check that all implemented (not abstract) classes have a foo attribute"""        
        Class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs)
        if not Class.Meta.abstract:
            print(Class)
            print('Class.Meta.ordering:', Class.Meta.ordering)  # Sanity check
            print('Class.Meta.abstract:', Class.Meta.abstract)
            if not hasattr(Class, 'foo'):
                raise NotImplementedError('Please add a foo attribute')
        return Class


class MyAbstractModel(models.Model, metaclass=MyMeta):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ('-name',)
```

Prints:

```
<class 'myapp.models.base.MyAbstractModel'>
Class.Meta.ordering: -name
Class.Meta.abstract: False
```

Add raises (even though it should not raise because it is an abstract class):

```
NotImplementedError: Please add a foo attribute
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong attribute, namely `Class.Meta`. Since this attribute will be inherited by any child classes Django actually [modifies <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/37c5b8c07be104fd5288cd87f101e48cb7a40298/django/db/models/base.py#L355-L361) it for abstract models:

> ```py
> if abstract:
>     # Abstract base models can't be instantiated and don't appear in
>     # the list of models for an app. We do the final setup for them a
>     # little differently from normal models.
>     attr_meta.abstract = False
>     new_class.Meta = attr_meta
>     return new_class
> ```

The attribute Django actually uses behind the scenes (All of the attributes are properly copied over to it) is `_meta`. Hence if you write the following you'll get the expected result:

```py
if not Class._meta.abstract:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract is False because children classes don't become abstract classes themselves. You need to explicitly set it True.
There is info about that in the docs.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/

Comment: There are no child classes in the code, and I mentioned in the post I understand this point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).